# MongoDB query comparing 2 fields in same collection for php

Tags: php, mongodb, comparison

I had a collection,

```
[ID] => 122344
[one] => Value 1
[two] => Value 2
[Session_id] => 73fdb9f3qf8gfejrv5e4nj0q22
[ses_id] => 73fdb9f3qf8gfejrv5e4nj0q22
[Date] => 2013-08-29


[ID] => 122345
[one] => Value 1
[two] => Value 2
[Session_id] => 73fdb9f3qf8gfejrv5e4nj0q22
[ses_id] => 46575876eqf8gfejrv5e4nj0q22
[Date] => 2013-08-29


[ID] => 122346
[one] => Value 1
[two] => Value 2
[Session_id] => 73fdbgrytj9v5e4nj0q22
[ses_id] => 73fdb9f3qf8gfejrv5e4nj0q22
[Date] => 2013-08-29
```

I have to get the values where 'Session_id' not equal to 'ses_id'. I think you understood my problem. Thanks in advance. And, Note. I want the code for php.

Comment: You'll need to do this via the aggregation framework or within your application - it's not currently possible to use a field on the right hand side of a comparison.  See here for the feature request https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7623, see here for an example of how to use the aggregation framework: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7621.  You might want to reexamine your application architecture.  Can you detect this when you're setting the Session_id or ses_id instead of trying to look for it later?

Answer (score 0):

The [SERVER-7623](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7623) ticket that Mason referred to in his comment above will definitely support this, after it is implemented.

For the time being, you will have to resort to the [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where/#op._S_where) query operator, which takes a string of JavaScript code and allows you select documents where the expression would evaluate to true (the current document is available as `this`). There are examples in the documentation that cover your exact use case. Be aware of the performance caveats of `$where` (e.g. regarding indexes), which are also discussed there.